# PHP Unix Timestamp Strtotime Error

Tags: php, unix-timestamp, strtotime

I have a website that logs the date of an article posted as a timestamp and converts it to full date. Testing this on localhost works fine but on the live version it displays the date as:

31st December 1969

Here is the code that I'm using:

```
$article_added = $article["added"];
$article_added = date('l jS F Y', strtotime($article_added));
```

Comment: Show us a valid value for `$article["added"]`

Comment: probably `$article["added"]` comes from the database and it has value `0` (or `NULL` or empty) in the live environment?

Comment: If $srticle['added'] is valid then I think it should work. [see here](https://eval.in/98205)

Comment: No the value is `1391610991`, which I've tested on a unix converter too

Comment: So if its already a timestamp then why are you using `strtotime` on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your date is already a timestamp so no need to use `strtotime()`

```
$article_added = date('l jS F Y', $article["added"]);
```